# jmeter active threads and csv - is this setup correct

Tags: jmeter

I am using jMeter to load test logging in and logging out of my application. I have a CSV with 500 uname and pwords, and I have also set the active threads to 500.

Is this the correct way to stimulate a load of 500 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From technical perspective - yes, JMeter will pick up credentials from CSV and send them along with the request.

---

However if you think about what happens in reality logging in and immediately logging out doesn't seem a realistic use case for me. The whole idea of load testing a web application is simulating **real users** as close as possible, it includes:

- Application usage scenario(s): how many users will be accessing your application at the same time and what users will be doing what things? For example given Stack OverFlow the vast majority of users are searching for answers by given criteria, some users are typing questions, some of them providing answers, and some of them are commenting. These all are different behavioral patterns which need to be accurately simulated by your load test
- Each user should have a "user session" which identifies him so application would distinguish different users so make sure you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in your Test Plan
- Real users use real browsers which are downloading images, CSS and JavaScript files using parallel thread pool (around 5 concurrent threads) to speed up page loading process. In order to mimic this behavior you need to configure HTTP Request samplers to download embedded resources and do it in parallel. You can apply this configuration to all the HTTP Request samplers via [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).
- Don't forget to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to mimic browser cache as real browsers normally cache embedded resources to disk and don't re-request them on subsequent calls.

So I would recommend reviewing your test scenario and/or load pattern and get familiarized with [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, this is a great answer. You are absolutely right that it isn't realistic. We use a third party identity provider and it turns out there are problems. The login logout is intended to test this third party app in siolation.

Comment: In that case all you need is to ensure you have all 500 users online as you may run into situation when some threads have already done this "login-logout" and were shut down and some have not been yet started. So make sure you have enough iterations on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and schedule your test to run longer than ramp-up period. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for details